Do electrostatic potentials never satisfy Neumann boundary conditions?
In electrostatics, one tries to solve
$$\nabla^2 \phi(\vec{r}) = -4\pi\rho(\vec{r}) \quad \forall \vec{r} \in V$$
subject to a Dirichlet boundary condition
$$\phi(\vec{r}) = s(\vec{r}) \quad \forall \vec{r} \in \partial V$$
or a "physical" boundary condition
$$-\frac{\partial\phi_a(\vec{r})}{\partial n} + \frac{\partial\phi_b(\vec{r})}{\partial n} = 4\pi\sigma(\vec{r}) \quad \forall \vec{r} \in \partial V. \tag{1}$$
It seems that $(1)$ is sometimes referred to as a Neumann boundary condition. However, this seems like a misnomer because strictly speaking the normal derivative of $\phi$ is discontinuous across a charged surface.
So, is it true that $(1)$ is a Neumann boundary condition, and I am misunderstanding?

What's the meaning of $\phi_a$ and $\phi_b$ ?

Suppose the surface charge density is located at some surface $S$. Then choose (arbitrarily) an "above" and "below" the surface. $\phi_a$ is the potential defined above the surface and $\phi_b$ is the potential defined below. @GiorgioP-DoomsdayClockIsAt-90

You are just asking about terminology. The names are such that in Dirichlet BC you are defining the field $\phi$'s values on the boundary, whereas in Neumann BC you are defining its normal derivative on the boundary; whether it is the discontinuity between above and below, or just one-sided, it probably doesnt matter. I don't know what you mean by "physical" BC.

A Neumann boundary condition requires a specified value for the normal derivative of $\phi$ on the boundary. Here there is a jump/discontinuity in the normal derivative on the boundary caused by the surface charge. I'm assuming that $\frac{\partial\phi_b(\vec{r})}{\partial n}$ and $\frac{\partial\phi_a(\vec{r})}{\partial n}$ vanish above and below the surface respectively. The definition for the Neumann boundary condition sitll holds.
